# undefined method `title' for #<Instrument id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1...............> Did you mean? tiitle tiitle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

i am a newbie and currently learning ruby on rails, i am gwtting an error where when i submit the Create button (for creating an instrument with the details filled in form) can anyone help me

Also you people might be thinking why i named it 'tiitle' and not 'title', its because i by mistakely created a table Instrument with the column tiitle:string and migrated it, so i thought to keep it like that way and continue...

instruments_controller.rb

```
class InstrumentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_instrument, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /instruments or /instruments.json
  def index
    @instruments = Instrument.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  # GET /instruments/1 or /instruments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /instruments/new
  def new
    @instrument = current_user.instruments.build
  end

  # GET /instruments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /instruments or /instruments.json
  def create
    @instrument = current_user.instruments.build(instrument_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @instrument.save
        format.html { redirect_to instrument_url(@instrument), notice: "Instrument was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @instrument }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @instrument.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /instruments/1 or /instruments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @instrument.update(instrument_params)
        format.html { redirect_to instrument_url(@instrument), notice: "Instrument was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @instrument }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @instrument.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /instruments/1 or /instruments/1.json
  def destroy
    @instrument.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to instruments_url, notice: "Instrument was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_instrument
      @instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def instrument_params
      params.require(:instrument).permit(:brand, :model, :description, :condition, :finish, :tiitle, :price, :image)
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @instrument, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col mx-auto">
      <div class="card mt-2 mx-auto p-4 bg-light">
        <div class="card-body bg-light">

        <div class = "container">
                          
        <div class="controls">
      
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.input :tiitle, input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>
              </div>
            </div>

            
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.input :model, input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.input :price %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 

        </div>
        </div>

    <%= f.input :description %>

    <%= f.label :condition %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            
            <%= f.input_field :condition, collection: Instrument::CONDITION, prompt: "Select Condition" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <%= f.label :brand %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :brand, collection: Instrument::BRAND, prompt: "Select Brand" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <%= f.label :finish %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :finish, collection: Instrument::FINISH, prompt: "Select Finish" %>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <%= f.input :image, as: :file, input_html:{ multiple: true, class:"file-input instrument-image" }, label: false, wrapper: false %>
  </div>  
    </div>
      </div>
        </div>
          </div>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Create instrument", class: "btn btn-success create-instrument-btn" %>
      </div>
    

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <%= link_to "Cancel", instruments_path, class: "btn btn-danger cancel-instrument-btn" %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



<% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# This file is the source Rails uses to define your schema when running `bin/rails
# db:schema:load`. When creating a new database, `bin/rails db:schema:load` tends to
# be faster and is potentially less error prone than running all of your
# migrations from scratch. Old migrations may fail to apply correctly if those
# migrations use external dependencies or application code.
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_11_01_061215) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "instruments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "brand"
    t.string "model"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "condition"
    t.string "finish"
    t.string "tiitle"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 5, scale: 2, default: "0.0"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

instrument.rb (model)

```
class Instrument < ApplicationRecord
    
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    belongs_to :user, optional: true

    validates :title, :brand, :price, :model, presence: true
    validates :description, length: { maximum: 1000, too_long: "%{count} is the maximum allowed characters" }
    validates :title, length: { maximum: 140, too_long: "%{count} is the maximum allowed characters" } 
    validates :price, numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { maximum: 7 } 

    BRAND = %w{ Fender Gibson Epiphone ESP Martin Dean Taylor Jackson PRS Ibanez Charvel Washburn }
    FINISH = %w{ Black White Navy Blue Red Clear Satin Yellow Seafoam }
    CONDITION = %w{ New Excellent Mint Used Fair Poor }



end
```

in the error, it says **undefined method title for #<Instrument id: nil**, brand: "Charvel", model: "model test",..............
but there isn't any column of 'id' in the instruments table and i am exhausted trying to debug myself and googling and i came here to get answers.

Comment: You spell "title" wrong in your migration (see line 23 of your schema.rb `t.string "tiitle"`. As you noted this was intentional but then you need to change your validations to match (see lines 7 & 9 of your instrument.rb file)

Comment: As an aside you do not have to keep it that way you can create a simple migration to fix it eg. `rename_column :instruments, :tiitle, :title` (then you will have to fix all the places you reference `tiitle`)

Comment: oh yeah! my bad, didnt notice the validations, also thanks alot!! really appreciate it :D